# Visual Studio - App conception and "The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects" error

Tags: algorithm, visual-studio, user-controls, handle, explorer

I have an app that gives me the **"The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects" error**, because it generates too many user controls. To understand what I'm facing, I will use an example. Let think about a Windows Explorer window into which I will show some UserControls.

**My user can save a lot of things** and I cannot have all the time a control of what he saves and where he saves it. These things can be grouped or not into hierarchical groups. And at a moment, **I will need to show all of them inside a form with a scrollbar** using one or many treeviews-like-display with a header for each of them.

Each of these displayed item is shown **using 3 kind of UserControl, that contains pictures and  labels** (each of these 3 controls has a different visual representation). And **when I have more than about 3000 items to display, I reach the 10000 handles limit**, because there seems to be at least 3-4 handles by UserControls.

So I will need to limit the number of created UserControls used for display.
 But how... ? What is the best way to handle this ?

I'm facing here a **conception problem** and after thinking about it, I'm finding a **lot of possible solutions**. Each of them **will need a deep rework** of my app, and I'd like to know **if you know a good way to do this**.

I could for example manage all the items 'virtualy' as if they were real UserControls and only display those who are in the visible area (thinking about the scrollbar).
But how ? With onscreen graphic writing and no more UserControls ? But then I will loose all the benefits of using the visual and event power offered by Visual Studio, and I fear a terrible bad performance. And I have some specific and complex displays that are automaticaly handled by Visual Studio controls. And I really don't want to have to rewrite Visual Studio controls :-)
Or creating-destroying the needed/non-needed UserControls on-the-fly ? Then I fear also a terrible bad performance if I have a lot of items to deal with.

Do you know what is best way to do such a thing ?

As a comparison, I notice that a Windows Explorer can show tons of items without problems. But with an easy trick I can't use : all the explorer items are the same height so it's easy here to prepare a bunch of controls that will receive a content to show.

Comment: This web site has over 10 million questions.  Given enough time, you can look at them all.  But of course it doesn't generate a page that shows all 10 million of them.  Somewhere between 10 and 50 items per view is plenty and all you can expect the user to want to digest, 3000 of them is just sloppy UI.

Comment: @HansPassant:Of course, but this is not the problem. You can have a folder into wich you can put 20.000 files if you want. And these can be viewed into a tree folder window, even if you don't see them all at once. I guess all the 20.000 files are not in display even "hidden" at a time, but I'm wondering the more efficient way to deal with them without creating 20.000 UserControls (keeping the sort order, drawing onscreen or creating a User control for each, or part, of them, dealing with a ctrl-A, ...)

Comment: Separate State from UI. The active selection is stored in an in-memory list. When rendering an item, check whether it's selected in the list, then render it differently, don't rely on the UI to store all your state. You could also custom draw the UI, which requires no handles, except for the panel you're drawing on and the pens you use to draw.